# Maximizing a piecewise-linear convex function

Tags: solver, constraint, linearization, nonconvex-programming

<sub>**Note:** Initially [posted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/385971) on MathOverflow.</sub>

---

I am working on an optimization problem where some of the terms of the objective function to maximize are expressed as a piecewise linear function of variables:

$$ z =  \begin{cases} 
      c^- x, & x \leq 0 \\
      c^+ x, & x    > 0 \\
   \end{cases} $$

as depicted below

[image: objective function plot]

When I have $c^- \geq c^+$, I can solve the problem by adding a new variable $x'$, and two constraints:

- $x' \leq c^- x $
- $x' \leq c^+ x $

But what do I do when $c^- < c^+$ ? I don't think there is a way to express the problem as a linear  programming problem in that case, is there ?

I have heard about [SOS constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_ordered_set). Are they the canonical way to solve this kind of problem ? If my problem contains many such piecewise linear functions, is it reasonable to expect a solver from being able to solve such a problem with thousands of SOS1 constraints ?

#### Example

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & a \max(x,0) + b \min(x,0) + c \max(y,0) + d \min(y,0)\\ \text{subject to} & x,y \in [−1,1]\end{array}$$

Comment: These things are difficult to predict. Best advice is: try it out. In general: if I am  developing a large model and I did not try out many variants and formulations, I did not do my job.

Answer (score 3):

within CPLEX you can use piecewise linear function in the objective with all APIs.

Let me show how to do that in OPL. Let me use the example from [Making Optimization Simple](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/)

[Piecewise linear function](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoopiecewise.mod)

```
/*
let s now deal with a new information : for a given bus size if we take more than 4 then we get a 20% discount.
This moves our function cost from linear to piecewise linear. Let's have a look at how to deal with this in OPL.
 
We would then write:
*/



int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;

// If we take more than 4 buses for a given size, 20% cheaper for additional buses
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;

pwlFunction pricePerQuantity=piecewise{1->4;0.8};

assert forall(k in 1..4 ) pricePerQuantity(k)==k;
assert forall(k in 5..10) as:abs(pricePerQuantity(k)-4-(k-4)*0.8)<=0.00001;
 
minimize
 costBus40*pricePerQuantity(nbBus40)  +pricePerQuantity(nbBus30)*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}
```

NB: I am an IBMer

Comment: In your example, the optimization domain is still convex, isn't it ? This is the equivalent of the case where $c^- \geq c^+$ in my original question, which can be solved with traditional linear programming. Would your example work as well and give an optimal solution in a reasonable amount of time if taking more buses had an **extra** fare associated to it ?

Comment: Hi, if not convex it will work. Could be slower sometimes.

Comment: Do you know what cplex uses to be able to solve this class of problems ? If there is a large number of places where the optimization domain is not convex, how can it find an optimal solution in a reasonable amount of time ?